# Running Two Functions at the Same Time in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have created a class library in my project which scans a series of files. In my main project which uses this DLL as a reference, I'd like to create a progress bar which shows how many file have been scanned so far.

The dll class makes use of a foreach loop since it's purpose is to turn each file into a hash code. The foreach loop has been used to join each converted segment of a file together so that I can have a 512 bit long code, and then it proceeds to the next file.

I have defined a variable in the dll class which is -->

```
public static int value_ = 0;
```

This variable is updated at the the end of the foreach loop.

Now in my main project, I'd like to use this variable to update my progress bar at the same time the function in my class library project is running.

For example :

```
DLL.function();
pb.value = value_;
```

I'd appreciate any hint on how I can implement this.

Comment: basically, any kind of threading. `BackgroundWorker`, `Task`, `ThreadPool`, `Thread`, etc. Perhaps start with the MSDN examples for `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: The variable is updated at the end of each ITERATION of the foreach, or after execution of the foreach loop?

Comment: After each iteration of the foreach loop

Comment: Marc, I've just tried it as well as parallel invoke, etc but it is not working, that is why I'm posting in here!

Comment: The first function works but the second one doesn't

Comment: Using progress bars which go from 0 to 100% are harder to implement and often misleading to users since the last 20% of the work may take longer then the first 80%. I recommend using a spinning wheel, or a continuously sliding progress bar for any task which only takes a few seconds. The only time progress bars which indicate a finish are useful are in very long running tasks so that you may ensure something is progressing. If you just need a spinning wheel or something simple like that, no need to get a handle on your for-loops progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to do work and report progress.

```
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

And now you can have this progress report be triggered by an event you subscribe to.

```
worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
```

In doing so, you can create a progress bar than can update itself based on this `worker_ProgressChanged` event, triggered by your method.

Answer (score 0):

Your main program will have to call your function using a thread, the [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) can help you with this.

To update the progress bar you'll have to look at events and delegate. Everytime you process an item, you could raise an event. Then your main program could handle this event and update the progress bar.

Comment: This wouldn't work, as everything would still be running on the same thread.